# A and B share something

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sian Ede talking about a very interesting [video installation](http://www.concatenate.net.au/lynettewallworth/files/BIGlw2-3.jpg.jpg) by Australian artist Lynette Wallworth says:

> We both give and receive and we seem to hold the fate of the fragile
>   universe in the palms of our hands. **This is something which artists
>   and scientists can share** ([full context](https://books.google.com/books?id=iiE3RsvK248C&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=%22This%20is%20something%20which%20artists%20and%20scientists%20can%20share.%22&source=bl&ots=Cu20mkDiy6&sig=3a1zL8RJvdvRMuCBDNSEJVjXuU4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMInuWz6vu3yAIVwbQUCh36qwlB#v=onepage&q=%22This%20is%20something%20which%20artists%20and%20scientists%20can%20share.%22&f=false)).

Does the bold sentence want to say:

1. this is something that both artist and scientists can present to people.
2. this is something that both artists and scientists have similar beliefs and ideas about.
3. this is something that artists and scientists can have in common.

I think that #3 is OK. Am I right? Every now and then I have the same problem encountering the structure "A and B share something".

Comment: I kinda doubt many scientists seriously think humanity could significantly affect the fate of the whole *universe*. According to our best theories, most of the universe (or increasingly these days, *multiverse*) is so far away (in space, time, or other "dimensions") that we probably can't even interact with it at all, let alone affect its long-term fate).

Answer (score 0):

I read #3 also, and the larger context didn't change it for me either.

But you're correct in that it is ambiguous - #1 is also valid.

#2 is categorical, and the inclusion of 'can' in the original sentence excludes that interpretation.

Unless I'm not seeing something, I'm not sure why you suggested that (?)

Comment: What do you think the pronoun *this* represents?

Comment: The holding of the fate of the fragile universe in the palms of their hands... But that isn't *certain*...  'seems' mixes things up a little, and there is the initial statement about giving and receiving too. But I'm going to keep things simple and go with the fate of the universe stuff (heh heh)

Comment: Then, I don't think No. 3 works.

Comment: Are you going to say any more on the topic? Why are your comments dependent on what I think 'this' referred to?

Answer (score 0):

From the three interpretation options you presented, I think #1 works best.

In broader context, the sentence seems to mean that there's a message that both scientists and artists can share with the world.

And the message is we hold the fate of this fragile universe in our hands.

I do not rule out #3, but I read it like #1.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but there is ambiguity itself in saying that "And the message is we hold the fate of this fragile universe in our hands." - the message they are trying to convey vs. the message they may have failed to convey...  Oh boy, this is hard to communicate! I have *very* likely failed to convey anything like what I'm trying to myself :)